# Class diagram conversion to relational model; Inheritance, and a table for matching

Tags: inheritance, uml, relational-database, class-diagram, use-case

For a school project, I'm supposed to design the systems of a previous semester's project. We're using UML, creating an extremely simple use case diagram (no `<<extend>>` type nonsense, just actors pointing at use cases inside of a system), from which we make a class diagram, then a relational model.

Use Case and Class Diagram attempts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last diagram is just me eventually thinking that maybe my use cases were the issue.

My application lets people/restaurants list food they're willing to donate. Charities that feed the homeless request food. If there's a match, the charities can create a truck route to pick up food from all their matches.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to represent matching, as well as if this diamond of the FoodItems and matching connecting to route makes any sense. I know inheritance is generally a bad idea in relational modeling. Is it just a matter of having FKs everywhere? I feel like I'm walking in circles.

Comment: You question is too broad, I think. So I leave @christope's answer as it is. You'r 2nd UC diagram is as good as the first one if you want to additionally show that you include a map API. That will just constraint the system in that it must provide access to such an API, whilst the first diagram leaves that open.

Comment: About your UC diagram, if you use the convention "actor on the right is a primary actor and actor on the left is a secondary actor", it means that's "Input food items" is a use case activate by the system himself. That's could be but it is what you want ?

Comment: @granier The convention is "primary at the left" IIRC. But it's a convention, not a law.

Comment: @Kilian, did I say that's a law, I wrote " if you use the convention "

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank you, I wasn't actually sure if I was being broad. The revisit of the use cases was out of desperation because I thought my headache might've been from planning. I'm going to just brute force my way through a relational model then maybe check back here.

Comment: @granier I don't think the OP is make use of the convention. `Donor` and `Charity` are both primary actors. Only the `Maps API` is a secondary one.

Comment: Is this a real-world app? It seems greedy that charities would make requests. I worked in a food bank and they take what they can get. If you developed the use-cases in detail, I think the "stakeholders and interests" would reveal that you don't need to distinguish between `DonorFoodItem` and `CharityFoodItem`. They're probably the same thing (Charity would just flag the Donor's item as useful/interesting).

Comment: I lurk the [tag:uml] questions, and I'm always curious why few people do conceptual modeling as suggested in DDD and Larman's methodology. That is, model the problem conceptually rather than an implementation of the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This object relational mapping topic can be quite complex.  But looking at your diagram, here an oversimplified rules of thumbs:

- Map each class with no generalization and no specialization to a relational table.  When [ID fields](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityField.html) are present, these will act as primary key.
- Map each of your classes having two specialization, to one relational table that combines the fields of the class and all the fields of its specialization. This technique is called [single inheritance table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html).  It's not always a good solution, but in your cas it could definitively fit.
- For each one to n relationship (`1 - 1..*`, or `1-0..*`) add the primary key (ID) on the 1 side as foreign key in the table on the n side. Do this also for the your aggregates. This is called [foreign key mapping](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html).
- For your n to n link (`1..* - 1..*`) you need to add a relational table, with the ID of the two linked tables (each defined as foreign key, and both together as a combined primary key).  This is called [association table mapping](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html).
- for your one to one aggregation in the second `ItemMatch`, I think it cwould be sufficient to add two fields corresponding each to a `foodItemID` (use different names).
- You also need to define as optional (nullable) the foreign keys that you've added as result of a `0..*`  relation

Additional readings:

- Martin Fowler's excellent book "[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html)" explains the pros and cons of several mapping strategies for inheritance in full details if want to know more.  In addition to the simple single inheritance table, you'll find also more complex alternatives approaches like [class table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html), [concrete table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) and [inheritance mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/inheritanceMappers.html).
- Web article [Mapping object to data model](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3564/85444_mappingobjec.html) suggested by [granier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724677/granier) in the comments (thanks !)

Comment: And you should define type matching : what SGBD type for int, float, String and so on. And you can look to the two others solutions to transform specialization ( see this, it explains the whole : https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3564/85444_mappingobjec.html)

Comment: @granier definitively an interesting resource ! Thanks for the tip: I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: your're welcome :) happy to have contribute in a positive way.

Comment: As usual I recommend Bittner/Spence when it comes to use case synthesis, though the OP already did a good job here.

Comment: @Christophe Thank you for jarring loose some old concepts I'd forgotten. I forgot to mention we had created an ERD for the project last semester. I thought that I was ignorant of some kind of divide between ERDs because my professor didn't seem to care for the ERD our previous professor thought highly of. I must have gone too far in the opposite direction! Thank you very much.