# How to define a class diagram from an entity relationship diagram?

Tags: entity-framework, uml, entity-relationship

I'm currently working on a project in which we're required to define a Entity Relationship Diagram and a UML Class Diagram from a set system.

I've successfully managed to define the ERD. It required me to break down information from a specification and form them into entities and then define a relationship between the entities to represent the system.

Now that I've done that I'm now onto the UML Class Diagram, but the only issue is I have no idea how to incorporate what I've defined inside my ERD into a UML Class Diagram as I've been told the structure between both diagrams are quite different.

- Do entities from the ERD in a sense serve as a class in the UML?
- Do the attributes from the entities in the ERD form the attributes in
  the classes?
- How can you easily define what attributes and methods you make public,
  private, and protected?

I understand a lot of the basics of UML and ERD on their own, but to take an entity relationship diagram and appropriately incorporate it into a UML is something i'm quite lost on where to start with.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but check their guidelines to make sure it is on-topic there first.

Comment: Just see [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169465/class-diagram-conversion-to-relational-model-inheritance-and-a-table-for-match#comment81309293_47169465)
and ask more if needed ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class diagram conversion to relational model; Inheritance, and a table for matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169465/class-diagram-conversion-to-relational-model-inheritance-and-a-table-for-match)